# TypeScript Conditional Function Argument name

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to create a function with arguments being optional depending on the value of first argument?

```
 post(item:"book"|"page", (if (item == "book") bookName: string), (if (item == "page") bookPage: number),  ): Observable<any> {
    return 
}
```

Is this or similar behaviour achievable with classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditionally you would use [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) to get this behavior, with multiple call signatures corresponding to each way you want people to call it:

```
// call signatures
function post(item: "book", bookName: string): void;
function post(item: "page", bookPage: number): void;
```

and then a single implementation which has to accept all the call signatures (but might be less strict than these signatures):

```
// implementation 
function post(item: "book" | "page", nameOrPage: string | number) {
}
```

This will behave as you want from the caller's side

```
post("book", "The Great Gatsby"); // okay
post("page", 123); // okay
post("book", 456); // error
post("page", "War and Peace"); // error
```

Although the drawback is that inside the implementation the compiler wouldn't realize that the `item` parameter can be used to narrow the `nameOrPage` parameter.  That is, you can't treat `item` like the *discriminant* of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions):

```
function post(item: "book" | "page", nameOrPage: string | number) {
    if (item === "book") {
        nameOrPage.toUpperCase(); // error! 'toUpperCase' does not exist on 'string | number'.
    } else {
        nameOrPage.toFixed(); // error! 'toFixed' does not exist on 'string | number'
    }
}
```

So you'd be forced to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or something like them:

```
// implementation 
function post(item: "book" | "page", nameOrPage: string | number) {
    if (item === "book") {
        (nameOrPage as string).toUpperCase();
    } else {
        (nameOrPage as number).toFixed();
    }
}
```

---

If the return type doesn't depend on the inputs, then nowadays you can get better behavior by using a single call signature rest argument list is of a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions), along with [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to assign the rest arguments to named parameters, and as of TypeScript 4.6 the compiler *will* [treat these parameters as discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-6.html#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions):

```
function post(...[item, nameOrPage]:
    [item: "book", bookName: string] |
    [item: "page", bookPage: number]
): void {

    if (item === "book") {
        nameOrPage.toUpperCase(); // okay
    } else {
        nameOrPage.toFixed(); // okay
    }
}
```

And from the caller's side it still looks like overloads:

```
post("book", "The Great Gatsby"); // okay
post("page", 123); // okay
post("book", 456); // error
post("page", "War and Peace"); // error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5AbhATgGwPYgBMkBvAWACgKlqkB6WpeEbbJKASwHNQAXAV0zQqNAGZ9g8Hu1zAkMXFB4AKdjwhgAXEgBEAI1y4A1toA0SfUYBy4CFsWZ2wTgEotaXOwIBuYdTESpGTkFZVV1LW04TghTcwNDAAUQaK1gPjBdLFckd08fSnIaOgZ2MBhsdQhgHhBA2V8kf0lpWXlFFTVNHQtjJAAfHSiYs1BIFEwklLYeByd+pDSMrJIGovYRJA71JABePe747WcVwqKz6lGIccmIADoeXABVGBgsAGEQKAglZy9ipCwmFwmAAhEgAOQPZ6vTAfL7gpAEXDQBa4HgAgAe7EUSCC4Psjk480WmUw4Nuq3Om0u12SyE+01mLnuTxe70+31+lOoAF8AdgvicqWcaRM6SyAGLsDEQAg-P70AGYIGgiEPKUyggIpEo4BozHY9F4glzAYkrDg7lnJSim5IBnmzDOSXS2Xyq08hqegpFNrKPSHMzaAAqAAtkABxQS1JAR2pQXQATyOCoYRhAiYafqUkTpsQAjAAmADMv3+6czp2o2YDRliABYAKwANjLisBwKzIRzQ1i2gA6iBMPbgEQEhAEDE2wwO5gKBRvfPyJdYJOkI9gC0UCIAErQdFkH2icTNILZ24XgDaYTAIxstOiAF0NFbr50Ij1Yj1rJA7DNCY+-SvjeES9mYPQ3Kk6Sko+DTZLkRCHla6ybDeuz7LWxjHIewpFLa4pQmysIcvK5aGBmHr8oKOG4Rc95itELqaqRioVh6S5FIuVbBO0mF9mGkbRuicY8AmybTri5GVr63a5tEBYlhJbHcTWn5mE2rapkqKpdrxYE6IOw4gKOSDjpOKb-LOS48kAA)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's something exactly like what you want.

I would just use better typing.

```
interface Book {
    bookName: string
}
interface Page {
    bookPage: number
}

post(item:Book|Page): Observable<any> {
    return 
}
```